# Global state management in C (like React Redux or Vuex)

Tags: c

Yes, I know that global variables are *"evil"*. And before you call me *completely nuts*, just hear me out. When writing React or Vue apps we usually use global state management libraries like Redux or Vuex. They solve the global state problem by providing information on **what** changed the state and **when** the state was changed. It also makes it clear **where** the global state is coming from since you have to explicitly import it in the components you want to use.

So it seems to be ok to use global state *(variables)* in web frontend world. So why not also have the same architecture in C? Or perhaps there already exists such an approach?

Right now in C, you have to pass context around everywhere which seems a bit strange *(notice the game struct is being passed around everywhere)*

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct Game *game = create_game();

  init_game(game);      // <------------- (game) here
  game_run(game);       // <------------- (game) here
  game_terminate(game); // <------------- (game) here

  return 0;
}

// This functions could be in a different file
void init_game(struct Game *game)
{
  game->speed = 5;

  if (game->screen_width == 0) {
    game->screen_width = WINDOW_WIDTH;
    game->screen_height = WINDOW_HEIGHT;
  }

  game->size = 1;
}
```

I'm thinking maybe we could just call `get_game()` in other functions and files which will return the global `game` struct and then we can use it from anywhere. So it would be stored globally in one place. Please correct me if my thinking here is completely wrong.

Comment: @user253751 sure, but why is nobody doing it?

Comment: possibly because what if they want to have more than one game in the same process? they would have to go and change all the code, if they don't do it that way to begin with.

Comment: @user253751 You could always make an array of `games[]`

Comment: you could. then you have to pass context around everywhere which is the game number. May as well use a pointer - isn't `game->` more convenient to type than `games[game]`?

Comment: however it's unlikely someone would want to put more than one game *window* in the same process (multiple games would probably be an invisible situation, like an AI simulation or a multiplayer server). A lot of people just put everything in one of these structs instinctively.

Comment: There is more to this, and most of it is opinion-based. You might want to do some research on the design pattern "singleton" and why it is regarded as an anti-pattern today, and on unit testing. Reading some stuff of professional C and C++ also helps.